# Prevent Checkbox click from activating drop down

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox, html-table

I'm working on a dynamic table where I have 2 check boxes in the first/left column, the next td's are a program name and a date, and php loops through all of the available programs.

When the user clicks on a row more information drops down via jQuery plugin.

As it sits now, when you click on the check boxes, the dropdown is activated, this isn't what I need it to do.

How do I stop the row dropping down when the checkboxes are clicked?

This is all from the jExpand plugin: [jExpand](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/expandable-rows/)

Script in head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
     $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
     $("#report tr:first-child").show();

     $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
         $(this).next("tr").toggle();
         $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
     });
     //$("#report").jExpand();
 });
 </script>
```

Script in file:

```
(function($){
$.fn.jExpand = function(){
    var element = this;

    $(element).find("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $(element).find("tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $(element).find("tr:first-child").show();

    $(element).find("tr.odd").click(function() {
        $(this).next("tr").toggle();
    });

}    
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="report">
    <tr>
        <th>Master/Registration</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Program Name</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="pid[]" type="checkbox" class="eventCodeCheck" value="<?php echo $row_programs['{table-column}']; ?>" />
            <input name="pid[]" type="checkbox" class="eventCodeCheck" value="<?php echo $row_programs['{table-column}']; ?>" />
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_programs['{table-column}']; ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_programs['format_date']; ?></td>
        <td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <h4>Additional information</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>Info</li>
                <li>Info</li>
                <li>Info</li>
             </ul>   
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php } while ($query = mysql_fetch_assoc($xxxxxxx)); ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Try capturing the event: `$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });`

Comment: You haven't stated what you want, just what you don't want.  To stop the expansion (which appears to be tied to clicking anywhere on odd rows, not the checkboxes), all you need to do is remove the `click` handlers from both your ready function, as well as in your jExpand function.  I doubt that's all you want, so you'll need to provide more detail.

Comment: Blender, your suggestion worked great!

Comment: I inserted  'code'$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });'code' right after $(document).ready(function(){. The check boxes are clickable and don't activate the drop-down on the rest of the table. Sorry if I left out any helpful info. My goal was to have two checkboxes on a table row, the row is clickable and drops down displaying more information. As I had it, activating a checkbox, would also activate the drop down. Which of course would never work. Thank you everybody for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [stop the propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation) of an event when the checkboxes are clicked:

```
$('input.eventCodeCheck').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Using $('input[type="checkbox"]') instead of eventCodeCheck worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#report tr.odd").click(function(e){
     if( e.target.type.toLowerCase() == 'checkbox') { 
     }
     else{  
       $(this).next("tr").toggle();
       $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
     }
});
```